# APIs share react-native

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/746as.png)

I want to share message to Snapchat and I use Share of react-native so I have a problem with APIs share of react-native. I want when I call Share.share({}) then open directly to app specify instead open action sheet.

[image]

Comment: i try use react-native-share but it not work for snapchat.

Comment: It is mentioned in their [ documentation ] (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share#static-values-for-social) that it do not support direct Snapchat sharing on iOS

Comment: I tried use it. but when i sharing through snapchat on android, param not passed. It just open app @Harshkurra